# How to search document with condition of not having exact object in array of objects?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of persons whose schema looks like the collection of following documents.

```
    Document: {

    name:
    age:
    educations:[{
title:xyz,
passed_year:2005,
univercity:abc},
{
title:asd
passed_year:2007,
univercity:mno
}],
current_city:ghi
}
```

Now I wanna show all the persons who has not done xyz education from abc university in year 2005.

I think two possible queries for this need but not sure which one to use as both of them are giving me the output

**Query 1:**

> db.persons.find({"education":{**$ne**:{$elemMatch:{"title":"xyz","passed_year":2005,"univercity":"abc"}}}})

**Query 2:**

> db.persons.find({"education":{**$not**:{$elemMatch:{"title":"xyz","passed_year":2005,"univercity":"abc"}}}})

I'm quite confused about operator $ne and $not, which one should I use with $elemMatch as both of them are giving me the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this `$elemMatch`: `{"title":"xyz","passed_year":2005,"univercity":"abc"}` I think you want to exclude any documents which contain an sub document in the educations array which contains all of these pairs:

- "title" : "xyz"
- "passed_year" : 2005
- "univercity" : "abc"

This query will achieve that:

```
db.persons.find({
    "educations": {
        $not: {
            $elemMatch:{"title": "xyz", "passed_year": 2005, "univercity": "abc"}
         }
     }
})
```

In your question you wrote:

> both of them are giving me the output

I suspect this is because your query is specifying `education` whereas the correct attribute name is `educations`. By specifying `education` you are adding a predicate which cannot be evaluated since it references a non existent document attribute so regardless of whether that predicate uses `$ne` or `$not` it will simply not be applied.

In answer to the question of which operator to use: `$not` or `$ne`: if you run the above query with `.explain(true)` you'll notice that the parsed query produced by Mongo is very different for each of these operators.

- Using `$ne`

  ```
  "parsedQuery" : {
      "$not" : {
          "educations" : {
              "$eq" : {
                  "$elemMatch" : {
                      "title" : "xyz",
                      "passed_year" : 2005,
                      "univercity" : "abc"
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Using `$not`:

  ```
  "parsedQuery" : {
      "$not" : {
          "educations" : {
              "$elemMatch" : {
                  "$and" : [ 
                      {
                          "passed_year" : {
                              "$eq" : 2005
                          }
                      }, 
                      {
                          "title" : {
                              "$eq" : "xyz"
                          }
                      }, 
                      {
                          "univercity" : {
                              "$eq" : "abc"
                          }
                      }
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

So, it looks like use of `$ne` causes Mongo to do something like this psuedo code ...

```
not educations equalTo "$elemMatch" : {"title" : "xyz", "passed_year" : 2005, "univercity" : "abc"}
```

... i.e. it treats the elemMatch clause as if it is the RHS of an equality operation whereas use of `$not` causes Mongo to actually evaluate the elemMatch clause.

Comment: thank you @glitch for correcting me but I would like to ask one more question, why did you specifically choose $not operator in your query and why not $ne? Although you are correct and your query is giving me the correct answer still, somehow I felt like it's obvious that $ne should have been correct operator.

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain the difference between Mongo's handling of `$ne` and `$not`. Hope that helps.