# MongoDB Finding by Array Item that Does Not Exist

Tags: mongodb

Hello and thanks for taking the time to help out. I am trying to find a mongoDB document that has an array.

The array is a list of IDs of users who have read the chat message.

I want to be able to find and/or count the docuemnts that do NOT contain the id of a specified user. That way I can tell who has or has not read the message.

Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated!

I know how to find a document that has an array that contains a value.... but I do not know how to find a document that has an array that does NOT contain a value.

```
let chatsUnread = await Chat.find({
    chatRoom: rooms[i],
    readMessage: { $all: [!userId] },
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output also will be east if you can create https://mongoplayground.net/

Comment: You probably need $not $elemMatc, like described at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567107/how-to-search-document-with-condition-of-not-having-exact-object-in-array-of-obj)

Comment: Please share the schema structure, so that we can construct the query.